# ParseError using JGroups for HornetQ in WildFly 9

Tags: wildfly, hornetq, jgroups

Currently I am using WildFly 9. We are trying to configure TCP-based load sharing with HornetQ. We have use JGroups for dynamic discovery, and we have added following setting in our standalone configuration file.

```xml
<broadcast-groups>
    <broadcast-group name="my-broadcast-group">
        <jgroups-file>jgroups-stacks.xml</jgroups-file>
        <jgroups-channel>hornetq_broadcast_channel</jgroups-channel>
        <broadcast-period>2000</broadcast-period>
        <connector-ref connector-name="netty-connector"/>
    </broadcast-group>
</broadcast-groups>
<discovery-groups>
    <discovery-group name="dg-group1">
        <jgroups-file>jgroups-stacks.xml</jgroups-file>
        <jgroups-channel>hornetq_broadcast_channel</jgroups-channel>
        <refresh-timeout>10000</refresh-timeout>
    </discovery-group>
</discovery-groups>
<cluster-connections>
    <cluster-connection name="tcp-based-cluster-node1-to-node2">
        <address>jms</address>
        <connector-ref>netty</connector-ref>
        <retry-interval>500</retry-interval>
        <use-duplicate-detection>true</use-duplicate-detection>
        <forward-when-no-consumers>true</forward-when-no-consumers>
        <max-hops>1</max-hops>
        <discovery-group-ref discovery-group-name="dg-group1"/>
    </cluster-connection>
</cluster-connections>
```

I have do configuration from [this documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/hornetq/2.3.0.Final/docs/user-manual/html/clusters.html#d0e10785), but still I faced issue here with `jgroup-file`. It is give following error:

```
Caused by: javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: ParseError at [row,col]:[393,21]
Message: WFLYCTL0198: Unexpected element '{urn:jboss:domain:messaging:3.0}jgroups-file' encountered
    at org.jboss.as.controller.parsing.ParseUtils.unexpectedElement(ParseUtils.java:89)
    at org.jboss.as.messaging.MessagingSubsystemParser.handleUnknownBroadcastGroupAttribute(MessagingSubsystemParser.java:739)
    at org.jboss.as.messaging.Messaging13SubsystemParser.handleUnknownBroadcastGroupAttribute(Messaging13SubsystemParser.java:182)
```

Here, issue is file was not found at server run time. As per document we have to set in resource folder but in HornetQ WildFly server have no resource folder so where we can set file and share load with multiple queue?

So my question is  first we are on right way or do we need to do any other configuration for the same?

Comment: HI, i have already do all configuration in `standalon-full.xml` file. currently i am using wildfly 9 version. if `jgroup-file` configuration  is not supported so how we can share load between 2 hornetq. i have already try with static connector but we are not achieving same.

Answer (score 0):

The [documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/hornetq/2.3.0.Final/docs/user-manual/html/clusters.html#d0e10785) you're looking at is for HornetQ, not for WildFly. WildFly has a unique XML format which is 100% independent of HornetQ's format, although they are very similar in many places in early versions of WildFly. However, WildFly doesn't support the `jgroups-file` configuration element you're attempting to use. Only standalone HornetQ supports that.

You should look at the `standalone-full-ha.xml` file that ships with WildFly 9. It has an example of JGroups configuration, e.g.:

```xml
        ...
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:jgroups:3.0">
            <channels default="ee">
                <channel name="ee"/>
            </channels>
            <stacks default="udp">
                <stack name="udp">
                    <transport type="UDP" socket-binding="jgroups-udp"/>
                    <protocol type="PING"/>
                    <protocol type="MERGE3"/>
                    <protocol type="FD_SOCK" socket-binding="jgroups-udp-fd"/>
                    <protocol type="FD_ALL"/>
                    <protocol type="VERIFY_SUSPECT"/>
                    <protocol type="pbcast.NAKACK2"/>
                    <protocol type="UNICAST3"/>
                    <protocol type="pbcast.STABLE"/>
                    <protocol type="pbcast.GMS"/>
                    <protocol type="UFC"/>
                    <protocol type="MFC"/>
                    <protocol type="FRAG2"/>
                    <protocol type="RSVP"/>
                </stack>
                <stack name="tcp">
                    <transport type="TCP" socket-binding="jgroups-tcp"/>
                    <protocol type="MPING" socket-binding="jgroups-mping"/>
                    <protocol type="MERGE3"/>
                    <protocol type="FD_SOCK" socket-binding="jgroups-tcp-fd"/>
                    <protocol type="FD"/>
                    <protocol type="VERIFY_SUSPECT"/>
                    <protocol type="pbcast.NAKACK2"/>
                    <protocol type="UNICAST3"/>
                    <protocol type="pbcast.STABLE"/>
                    <protocol type="pbcast.GMS"/>
                    <protocol type="MFC"/>
                    <protocol type="FRAG2"/>
                    <protocol type="RSVP"/>
                </stack>
            </stacks>
        </subsystem>
        ...
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:messaging:3.0">
            <hornetq-server>
                ...
                <broadcast-groups>
                    <broadcast-group name="bg-group1">
                        <jgroups-stack>udp</jgroups-stack>
                        <jgroups-channel>hq-cluster</jgroups-channel>
                        <connector-ref>http-connector</connector-ref>
                    </broadcast-group>
                </broadcast-groups>
                <discovery-groups>
                    <discovery-group name="dg-group1">
                        <jgroups-stack>udp</jgroups-stack>
                        <jgroups-channel>hq-cluster</jgroups-channel>
                    </discovery-group>
                </discovery-groups>
                <cluster-connections>
                    <cluster-connection name="my-cluster">
                        <address>jms</address>
                        <connector-ref>http-connector</connector-ref>
                        <discovery-group-ref discovery-group-name="dg-group1"/>
                    </cluster-connection>
                </cluster-connections>
                ...
            </hornetq-server>
        </subsystem>
        ...
```

It's worth noting that WildFly 9 was release in July of 2015, almost 7 years ago now. The current version is 26.1.0.Final. I **strongly** encourage you to upgrade to a more recent version.